# jboss server log file

Tags: jboss

I am trying to run jboss.

But I get the following error:

```
    [javac] C:\Program Files\jbpm-5.0-try3\jbpm-installer\build.xml:518: warning
: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to
 false for repeatable builds
     [java] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
     [java] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
     [java] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for fu
rther details.
     [java] Task service started correctly !
     [java] Task service running ...
```

as well, it does not run on port:8080.

What could be the problem?

How can I see the log file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**About the log files:** 
jboss should have the log files in the folder `%JBOSS%\server\default\log`.

**About the port:8080:** 
 I would check whether some other server is configured to listen on 8080 already. Especially if you are doing a lot of experimantal installations you can end up with several Jbosses, Tomcats and Glassfishes listening at the same port, so most of the servers won't receive their requests. At least to me it has happened once (but don't tell anybody).

Comment: I don't have the log folder there! I am using version 4.2.3

Comment: I have `%JBoss%/server/default` but there is no log folder in there.

Comment: For jboss standalone, server logs are at %JBOSS%\standalone\log\server.log

Comment: For Mac users these are at $JBOSS/standalone/log/server.log where $JBOSS is your server root folder.

Comment: What is the log location for JBOSS 7.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

It ccould be that logging failed to initialize and further errors prevent your application from correct deployment.
Check this first:

```
Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing one (**and only one**) of `slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar` on the class path should solve the problem.

As of SLF4J version 1.6, in the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP) logger implementation.

Comment: Hi stacker, I'm currently using Hibernate 3 and i have a           slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar on my project's build. i have the same "Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error and i would like to know if i need to add another JAR to the projects build. thanks in advance, idan